# CSS menu bar wont show!!! class or ID problem?

Tags: css, menubar

Please help me with this insanity:

http://imageoneads.com/zenliver/

My menu bar worked fine & I accidently deleted or moved one of class or ID. Now it disappeared. All browsers Wont display the menu, except Firefox for Mac. This drives me nut....Cant believe I have to start over if I can't figure it out....Please help....Thanks ahead

tran006

Comment: As of now, your header styling is commented out.

Comment: "This drives me nut". *Insert crude pirate joke here*

Comment: It's okay. We've all been there, at some point.

Answer (score 1):

You missed a brace.

```
#header li a{
 padding: 0em;
  display:block;
 font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif
 font-size: 1em
 color: #fff;
 text-decoration:none;
 line-height: 30px;
 margin-right: 0.5em;
 } <----
```

Comment: @Tran:  First, you're missing a lot of semicolons (`;`) in your CSS defined in the HTML page. Second, your `main.css` is defining the `#header li a:link, #header li a:visited` with `color: #FFFFFF`. That's white text, on white background. Third, consider moving all your CSS code into `main.css` so it's easier to maintain. =]

Answer (score 0):

## header li a{

```
padding: 0em;
display:block;
font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif
font-size: 1em
color: #fff;
text-decoration:none;
line-height: 30px;
margin-right: 0.5em;
```

You have no end bracket on this.

Comment: It's all figured out. Im in the process of cleaning up the codes. Thanks every one.